# How can I use a model named Collector in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to do this in my controller:

```
 @collector = Collector.find(params[:id])
```

But when I do, I get this error:

```
 undefined method `find' for ActionController::MimeResponds::Collector:Class
```

How can I show that I'm trying to use the ActiveRecord model named Collector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to refer to the class prefixed by :: as in `::Collector`

Comment: The :: is a namespace resolution operator. When you prefix your class with :: it searches from the class under an empty namespace which is what you need. When you just use the class without :: prefix it tries to find it in the current context namespace which may conflict with existing classes in current context.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `Collector::find(params[:id])`